# Upload Picture from Phonegap to Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, cordova, image-uploading, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am making an app in which I want to upload picture to Server.

I chose google cloud service where I created bucket and now have followed [Video Instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=8ytpvQJNOU8) to upload file.
When I Used the code shown in video I could test it on localhost but later for my Cordova project google api doesn't seem to work. Do I need plugin for it? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Provide more info on why it doesn't work.

Comment: I have done some testing and research based on which I can say that request to google api server is not possible from file://. As the error says 'Blocked a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".' Please check the answer from google support team [Answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-javascript-client/nKs3T0UPxm0)

Comment: Hey xmd, did you succeed in this ? I'm pretty much looking for the same thing and have a hard time finding a good path to ride on.